# Mounting Azure File Share on Oracle Linux 7.7

Tags: azure, cifs, oracle-linux

I'm trying to mount Azure File Share in Oracle Linux 7.7 and it doesn't work in the latest kernel `4.1.12-124.31.1.1.el7uek.x86_64` (released Sep 2019).

I know that I must use encryption when connecting from outside of Azure region, but I'm not sure if the File Share is in the same region as VM as I don't have access to the Azure Portal.

I have tried mounting with options vers=3.0 and vers=2.1, both give permission denied. I have tried with smbclient and that works without any issues.

Does anyone know if this Oracle UEK kernel supports the cifs protocol needed by Azure File Share? This [article](https://docs.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/Azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-linux) mentions kernel 4.11 is needed, but I thought Oracle backported it in their kernel.

Also is there any way to see which protocol version smbclient used to connect? Using `-d 3` I can only see that it used NTLMSSP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try to install UEK5 kernel (built on 4.14.x upstream)
To get this kind of thing in-place, you just need to enable the UEK5 Yum channel and then update the system with "yum update" or the only kernel -- if you prefer -- with "yum update kernel-uek".
UEK4 (4.1.12.*) is based on 4.1.12 upstream and so it's quite older than 4.11.
For further details related to UEK and OL releases, you can check this page:

https://blogs.oracle.com/scoter/oracle-linux-and-unbreakable-enterprise-kernel-uek-releases

Comment: I see UEKR5 is default from OL7U6. Shouldn't it be automatically enabled and upgraded then? VM was deployed as 7.2 and I did `yum update` to 7.7. Or should I check in the future the releases and manually enable/upgrade to UEKR6 when that becomes available and default?

Comment: We do not force the upgrade of major kernel releases. If you started with OL7.2 with UEK4, you'll continue to get updates for UEK4 on your VM/Instance. If you want to switch to UEK5 kernel, you have to enable its proper Yum-Channel to then install/upgrade it.